# ExtJS5 Store filter "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm using the gpl version of extjs5.1.1 without sencha cmd.
In my application a Grid displays correctly a Store.
In the window, there is a checkbox wich code is :

```
{
    xtype    : 'checkbox',
    itemId   : 'employeeFilter',
    value    : false,
    boxLabel : 'Show inaktiv users',
    margin   : '0 5 0 5',
    listeners: {
        change: function(checkbox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
            var store = this.up('window').getComponent('employeeGrid').getStore();
            if (newValue) {
                console.log('clearFilter');
                store.clearFilter();
            } else {
                console.log('rightFilter');
                store.rightFilter();
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

The variable `store` points to the grid store correctly. I can see the messages 'clearFilter' and 'rightFilter' in the console.

The store code:

```
Ext.define('Chronos.store.manage.Employees', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    model      : 'Chronos.model.manage.Employee',
    autoLoad   : false,
    autoSync   : true,
    sortOnLoad : false,
    pageSize   : 0,

    rightFilter: function() {
        this.filterBy(function(record) {
            return record.get('rights') >= 0;
        });
    },

    proxy : {
        type   : 'ajax', // Ext.data.proxy.Ajax
        api    : {
            create  : 'api/management/employees.create.php',
            read    : 'api/management/employees.read.php',
            update  : 'api/management/employees.update.php',
            destroy : 'api/management/employees.destroy.php'
        },
        reader : {
            type         : 'json', // Ext.data.reader.Json
            rootProperty : 'records'
        },
        writer : {
            type         : 'json', // Ext.data.writer.Json
            encode       : true,
            rootProperty : 'record'
        }
    }
});
```

On window call, the checkbox  is unchecked and the filter is active because the grid listeners is:

```
    listeners: {
        render: function() {
            this.getStore().load();
            this.getStore().rightFilter(); // <<<<< if the function is called here, the problem exists, if not, the filter works perfectly !
        }
    },
```

The first time I check the checkbox the filter is cleared correctly and the message 'clearFilter' appears in the console. When I uncheck it, the message 'rightFilter' appears too, but the filter does not anything in the grid... and the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" appears.

Where am I wrong?

**Edit**: Actually the filter function only works fine once. It does not work any more after `clearFilter` is called...
I tried with `addFilter`/`removeFilter` with the same result.
My next try will be `setDisable`.
If someone has any (other) idea...

**Edit 2:** Test case [in fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ou6)
Now I know that the problem comes from function call in the render function. When this call is not done, the checkbox works perfectly, but on show, the checkbox state does not correspond to the display and I want to hide filtered items on show.

Any Idea ?

Comment: You need to post a test case.

Comment: Might be an oversight, but have you added the Store to the controller class. Or may be your this.up('window').getComponent fails.

Comment: The controller does not need to access to the store.Actually the variable `store` (this.up('window')...) points well to the grid store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function cannot be called just after the load, that's why load in render and filter in viewready (in afterrender it doesn't work either). The problem is solved !!

```
    listeners: {
        render: function() {
            this.getStore().load();
        },
        viewready: function() {
            this.getStore().rightFilter();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line is with **this**.

```
rightFilter: function() {
        this.filterBy(function(record) { // <<<<< this line sends an error the second time the function is called
            return record.get('rights') >= 0;
        });
    },
```

Can you please change the above code to

```
rightFilter: function(me) {
me.filterBy(function(record) { // <<<<< this line sends an error the second time the function is called
return record.get('rights') >= 0;
});
},
```

and the grid listener to pass store

```
listeners: {
        render: function() {
            this.getStore().load();
            this.getStore().rightFilter(this.getStore());
        }
    },
```

and the calling from combobox to

```
if (newValue) {
                console.log('clearFilter');
                store.clearFilter();
            } else {
                console.log('rightFilter');
                store.rightFilter(store);
            }
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it did not help. Thanks for your tip.